# Why can user create posts if `cannot :manage, Post` in Ability class (CanCanCan)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, cancancan

I'm implementing CanCanCan for the first time.

But am confused why users can still create posts when I've setup `cannot :manage, Post` in the `Ability` class.

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # if a non-signedin visitor
    cannot :manage, Post
  end
end
```

My understanding is that `:manage` applies to all actions, so the user should not be able to do anything with the `post` resource.

Can anyone advise?

Comment: Looks like just needed to add `load_and_authorize_resource` to `posts_controller.rb`. Then works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

have you added this around the index, show and edit pages CRUD links across your app? that will remove the link all together.. Im still new with cancancan but even with the load_and_authorize_resources I still had to add the if can? around my links and that resolved my problem.

```
<% if can? :manage, Post %> 
  <% link_to "something" some_path %> 
<% end %>
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to define the abilities of each user type inside the `Ability` class:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # if a non-signedin visitor

   # abilities of user of type PUBLISHER
   if user.role == "publisher"
     can :create, Post
     can :read, Post
     can :update, Post, user_id: user.id # users can only update their own posts

   # abilities of user of type ADMIN 
   elsif user.role == "admin"
    can :manage, :all # admin can do everything

   # abilities of non-users (e.g. they only can read posts)
   else
     cannot :manage, Post
     can :read, Post
  end
end
```

> Defining the abilities does not mean they are automatically
>   applicable in controllers.

Second, you need to include `load_and_authorize_resource` in each controller you want to apply the defined abilities to (e.g. the Post controller).